# Calling two javascripts functions onClick

Tags: javascript

Presently i have the following code on one of my web page-

```
<a href="http://ex.com" onclick="return popitup2()">Grab Coupon</a>
```

now I want to run one more script which is used in the following way -

```
onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'ex.com');return false;"
```

Now can someone tell me how do i call both of these javacsripts when the link is clicked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call the two functions in the onclick event handler:

```
<a href="http://ex.com" onclick="popitup2(); recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'ex.com'); return false;">Grab Coupon</a>
```

To avoid mixing markup with javascript I would recommend you attaching the `onclick` event for this particular link like this:

```
<a href="http://ex.com" id="mylink">Grab Coupon</a>
```

And in the `head` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var mylink = document.getElementById('mylink');
    if (mylink != null) {
        mylink.onclick = function() {
            var res = popitup2(); 
            recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'ex.com');
            return res;
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to return `popitup2()` to maintain OP's current function.

Answer (score 2):

Specify both of them in your link:

```
<a href="http://ex.com" onclick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'ex.com'); return popitup2();">Grab Coupon</a>
```

Comment: This syntax seems wrong. You cannot have multiple `return` statements in the `onclick` handler or at least it is not good.

Comment: without the return false in the function recordOutboundLink will it work in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a closure:

```
<a href="http://ex.com" onclick="return function(){ recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'ex.com'); return popitup2(); }()">Grab Coupon</a>
```

or just some better ordering:

```
<a href="http://ex.com" onclick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'ex.com');return popitup2();">Grab Coupon</a>
```