# How can I write JavaScript code in onClick function as well as I also want to call another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to write one JavaScript code line in onClick function and also to call another function in the same onClick. I have tried as follow:

```
<select onchange="updateSeatsDinnerCategory(3993); javascript: return function(){$(this).prop('disabled', true); return true;};" class="width-80" id="rowDinnerCategorySelect3993">
    <option value="-1">--select--</option>
    <option value="1">Family</option>
</select>
```

But it's not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210645/calling-two-javascripts-functions-onclick

Comment: @tas9 we can call multiple function, but i don't want to call functions but execute a line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function(){ ... }` is a function definition. If you want the code inside to be executated instantly, you need to also call it:

```
(function(){ ... })()
```

Your code then becomes:

```
<select onchange="updateSeatsDinnerCategory(3993); return function(){$(this).prop('disabled', true); return true;}();" class="width-80" id="rowDinnerCategorySelect3993">
    <option value="-1">--select--</option>
    <option value="1">Family</option>
</select>
```

Looking at your code better, (assuming it's the actual code you want to use), you don't need the IIFE, nor the return value (which is always true):

```
<select onchange="updateSeatsDinnerCategory(3993); $(this).prop('disabled', true);" class="width-80" id="rowDinnerCategorySelect3993">
    <option value="-1">--select--</option>
    <option value="1">Family</option>
</select>
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/agIVUfEt/1/edit

Comment: is the way i am using $(this) is corrent. I want to disable the same select

Comment: A simple `console.log(this)` would tell you all you need to know: http://jsbin.com/agIVUfEt/2/edit. Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<select onchange="updateSeatsDinnerCategory(3993);$(this).prop('disabled', true); return true;" class="width-80" id="rowDinnerCategorySelect3993">
<option value="-1">--select--</option>
<option value="1">Family</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
<select onchange="(function() {updateSeatsDinnerCategory(3993); $(this).prop('disabled', true); return false;})()" class="width-80"     id="rowDinnerCategorySelect3993">
    <option value="-1">--select--</option>
    <option value="1">Family</option>
</select>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c9Rk8/)

Answer (score 0):

Pass an optional callback to the updateSeatsDinnerCategory function

```
function updateSeatsDinnerCategory(seats, callback) {
    // do whatever you wanted to do

    if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') {
         callback.call(this);
    }
}
```

This way you can call the function if passed, and skip where you don't want.

```
// this will call the "standard version"
updateSeatsDinnerCategory(3993);

// this will execute the callback function as well
updateSeatsDinnerCategory(3993, function () {alert('lol'));
```

The callback does not have to be an anonymous function of course, just any function within scope will work.

**EDIT**

There are better ways of checking for undefined, but this is the easiest one.